# Add Button to Netflix Control Bar (Greasemonkey, AJAX, waitForKeyElements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, greasemonkey, netflix

I'm trying to add a button to the "control-bar" on Netflix using Greasemonkey. I've successfully added a style tag to the head and a script to body. Since Netflix uses AJAX for *everything*, I'm using [waitForKeyElements](http://pastebin.com/rsYsfKsk) to call the function to insert the button.

I've been using Firebug to look at Netflix's HTML (relevant code shown below). I'd like to insert another div for the new button as a child of the section. The button would fit between the volume button and player status.

```html
<section class="player-control-bar no-select" role="control-bar">
  <div class="player-control-button player-play-pause pause icon-player-pause" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Pause"></div>
  <div class="player-control-button volume icon-player-volume-full icon-player-volume-3" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Mute">
  <div class="player-status">
```

To make the addition, the waitForKeyElements function receives a jQuery selector (selectorTxt="section.player-control-bar") and a function name (actionFunction=addDiv) which are transferred as strings.

After the section object is stored to jNode, the addDiv function is called to insert the button. However, the div (fiv) won't append to the section.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Netflix Ajax
// @namespace   https://www.netflix.com/watch
// @include     https://*.netflix.com/watch*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements (
    "section.player-control-bar" // also tried: "div.player-status"
    , addDiv
);

function waitForKeyElements (
    selectorTxt,    /* Required: The jQuery selector string that specifies the desired element(s). */
    actionFunction, /* Required: The code to run when elements are found. It is passed a jNode to the matched element.*/
    bWaitOnce,      /* Optional: If false, will continue to scan for new elements even after the first match is found.*/
    iframeSelector  /* Optional: If set, identifies the iframe to search.*/
) {
    var targetNodes, btargetsFound;
 
    if (typeof iframeSelector == "undefined"){
        targetNodes     = $(selectorTxt);
    }
    else{
        targetNodes     = $(iframeSelector).contents ()
                                           .find (selectorTxt);
    }

    if (targetNodes  &&  targetNodes.length > 0) {
        btargetsFound   = true;
        /*--- Found target node(s).  Go through each and act if they
            are new.
        */
        targetNodes.each ( function () {
            var jThis        = $(this);
            var alreadyFound = jThis.data ('alreadyFound')  ||  false;
 
            if (!alreadyFound) {
                //--- Call the payload function.
                var cancelFound     = actionFunction (jThis);
                if (cancelFound)
                    btargetsFound   = false;
                else
                    jThis.data ('alreadyFound', true);
            }
        } );
    }
    else {
        btargetsFound   = false;
    }
 
    //--- Get the timer-control variable for this selector.
    var controlObj      = waitForKeyElements.controlObj  ||  {};
    var controlKey      = selectorTxt.replace (/[^\w]/g, "_");
    var timeControl     = controlObj [controlKey];
 
    //--- Now set or clear the timer as appropriate.
    if (btargetsFound  &&  bWaitOnce  &&  timeControl) {
        //--- The only condition where we need to clear the timer.
        clearInterval (timeControl);
        delete controlObj [controlKey]
    }
    else {
        //--- Set a timer, if needed.
        if ( ! timeControl) {
            timeControl = setInterval ( function () {
                    waitForKeyElements (    selectorTxt,
                                            actionFunction,
                                            bWaitOnce,
                                            iframeSelector
                                        );
                },
                300
            );
            controlObj [controlKey] = timeControl;
        }
    }
    waitForKeyElements.controlObj   = controlObj;
}

function addDiv (jNode) {
  var fiv = document.createElement('div');
  fiv.setAttribute("class", "player-control-button player-filter icon-player-play");
  fiv.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
  fiv.setAttribute("role", "button");
  fiv.setAttribute("aria-label", "Filter");
  fiv.setAttribute("on-click", "myFunction()"); 
  jNode.append(fiv);
  //Other Attempts:
  //fiv.insertBefore(jNode);
  //jNode.prepend(fiv);
  //jNode.appendChild(fiv);
  //jNode.before(fiv);
  //jNode.parent("section").appendChild(fiv);
}
```

I tested the exact same code just exchanging the section for the player-status class and it inserts the code for the button perfectly (just in the wrong place). From the div tag, I tried fiv.insertBefore(jNode), jNode.before(fiv), and jNode.parent("section").appendChild(fiv). Any idea why jNode won't append to the section?

Comment: Maybe the site constantly resets this element by recreating its contents. Attach your buttons after the section and use css to adjust size and position.

Comment: @wOxxOm That's what I've been trying to do. I've got the CSS inserted but the div tag for the button won't attach to the section.